# Old anime in the style of Conan Doyle' Lost World

Tags: jura-tripper

I'm looking for an old anime (from at least 10-15 years ago) similar to Conan Doyle' Lost World.

The crew of a ship end up in a prehistoric world (don't remember how). This world is ruled by priests that are against technology. They use dinosaurs for labor. There is also something like "the resistance" that is against the current regime imposed by the priests. The crew of this ship get caught in this conflict.

This world is not without technology though, very advanced technology (don't remember the context, maybe an alien race) like infinite power supplies, but it's illegal to use it and who does, does so in secret.

I only saw the first few episodes of this anime, I don't know how the story goes or how it ends. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be [Kyōryū Bōkenki Jura Tripper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jura_Tripper)?

[image]

From the [Anime News network synopsis](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=1767)

> On a school yachting trip, fifteen children of various ages are mysteriously transported to another world where dinosaurs still roam. While attempting to return home, they encounter talking dinosaurs, revolutionaries, pirates, a princess and primitive scientists. These unlikely allies help them escape from soldiers, bandits, vicious dinosaurs, and fanatical priests. Aggression between the two oldest boys leads to a split in ranks, and a sneaky double cross plot. Unlikely romances bloom in this tense atmosphere, and the group learns that each has strengths that can help them get home, if they work together. Losely based on the book Deux ans De Vacances, by Jules Verne in 1888.

And from a [plot synopsis from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jura_Tripper)

> While trying to find a way back home, the children learn more about the new world they're in, discovering the people and dinosaurs suffer from oppression by the king as well as the church's prohibition of science. They get into conflict with General Mosar who is interested in their advanced technology and consequently have to flee from the king's army as well as the priests who try to capture Zans, who incidentally is the son of White Wing, the famous but passed leader of the rebellion.

The show aired back in 1995 and consists of 39 episodes.